# Regex use hitEnd in scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

I´ve been watching this example for partial matcing

```
    String[] ss = { "aabb", "aa", "cc", "aac" };
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aabb");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("");

    for (String s : ss) {
      m.reset(s);
      if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : match%n", s);
      }
      else if (m.hitEnd()) {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : partial match%n", s);
      }
      else {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : no match%n", s);
      }
    }
```

And I would like to use, the `hitEnd` for my scala pattern matching regex

```
  val VERSION = "([0-2].0)"
  val MESSAGE = s"A message with version $VERSION".r

  def checkMessage(action: String): Boolean = {
    action match {
      case MESSAGE(version) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
```

What I want is that if someone type `A message with version 3.0` tell him that the message has a partial match, but the version he type was not correct.

Any idea how to use this `hitEnd` in scala?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a `Matcher` from a Scala compiled regex but I don't think it will do what you want. The string `"version"` is a partial match for the pattern `version [0-2].0`, but the string `"version 3.0"` is not.

```
val m = "version ([0-2].0)".r.pattern.matcher("")

for (s <- Seq("version 1.0", "v", "version ", "version 3.0")) {
  m.reset(s)
  if (m.matches)     println(f"$s%-11s : match")
  else if (m.hitEnd) println(f"$s%-11s : partial match")
  else               println(f"$s%-11s : no match")
}
```

Output:

```
version 1.0 : match
v           : partial match
version     : partial match
version 3.0 : no match
```

A different approach is to compile two patterns, one for the general case and one for the specific target.

```
val prefix  = "A message with version "
val goodVer = (prefix + "([0-2].0)").r
val someVer = (prefix + "(.*)").r

def getVer(str: String): String = str match {
  case goodVer(v) => s"good: $v"
  case someVer(v) => s"wrong: $v"
  case _          => "bad string"
}

getVer("A message with version 2.0")  //res0: String = good: 2.0
getVer("A message with version 3.0")  //res1: String = wrong: 3.0
getVer("A message with version:2.0")  //res2: String = bad string
```